# VBA copy named cells from one sheet and paste to another retaining names

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to copy a named cell and paste it into a new sheet and have the name transfer over?  Lets say for example I had a list of 5000 books and I wanted to index it so people didn't have to scroll through 4950 books to get to the "Z" section, they could just click a link and it would take them to the named cell "Section_Z".

With one sheet this would be easy but I'm using a `for each` loop in VBA to take specific items from a master list and divide them into three separate sheets based on some criteria.  Each separate sheet has to have an index like the use case mentioned above so when the cell named "Section_Z" copies over to Sheet2 it's name and relative location would also be copied to reflect Sheet2.

This is what I have so far:

```
 'for loop starts going through the master list

    for Each RowCount In Worksheets("Master List").ListObjects("MasterListTable").Range.Rows

    'if statements determine the category that the product should be placed in based on Category column G.

    If Cells(RowCount.Row, 7).Value Like "Retail*" Then
    TotalRowsRetail = TotalRowsRetail + 1

     'copy the row
       RowCount.EntireRow.Copy

       'select the retail sheet and paste the row corresponding with the current iteration (this does not look for the next blank row because this macro is intended to be run occasionally to totally refresh the sheets)

        Worksheets("Retail").Select
        Worksheets("Retail").Range("A" & TotalRowsRetail).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues





     ElseIf Cells(RowCount.Row, 7).Value Like "Corporate*" Then
    TotalRowsGroup = TotalRowsGroup + 1
       RowCount.EntireRow.Copy

        Worksheets("Corporate").Select
        Worksheets("Corporate").Range("A" & TotalRowsCorporate).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial



        Worksheets("Master List").Select


    Next RowCount

    'after the for each loop runs the tables in the retail and corporate sheets are resized to match the amount of data pasted in

    Worksheets("Retail").Select
     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RetailTable").Resize Range("$A$10:$G$" & TotalRowsRetail + 1)
     Worksheets("Corporate").Select
     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CorporatepTable").Resize Range("$A$10:$G$" & TotalCorporateGroup + 1)
```

The above macro works perfectly, I'm only posting it to try and give some context to what I am trying to do, which is essentially copy not just cell formatting ie 'ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` but also paste any named cells.

Comment: Description only is difficult to understand, and it vaguely sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Can you provide sample data with before and after results?

Comment: You can use a named range for the entire column (example "A:A") and make the macro look only up to the last filled cell, or you can use a named range only for the header, and use offsets to get the following values until you find an empty cell.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, based on the feedback I have edited the question thoroughly because I don't think the original wording fully conveyed what I am trying to do.

Comment: Named cells implies a Named Range.  What does that have to do with the sample code? `Range("Section_Z").Cut Sheet1.Range("A10")` will moved a the Named Range `Section_Z` to `Sheet1.Range("A10")` and retain its name.

Comment: You can name a range which is several cells but you can also name a specific cell, this is useful if you want to navigate to a specific place in the document.  Naming a cell effectively inserts a hyperlink destination into the document.  From the code I'm not cutting cells I'm copying so I don't know what the outcome with cutting a cell would be but as far as copying goes the cell does not retain it's name when it is copied over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I was able to cobble together a solution.

```
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Worksheets("Master List").Cells(RowCount.Row,_
     1).Name.Name & "_retail", RefersTo:=RetailSheet & intCount

   intCount = intCount + 1
```

We add a new name to to the workbook; `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add` the name comes from the existing name on the other sheet `Name:=Worksheets("Master List").Cells(RowCount.Row,1).Name.Name & "_retail"` the `& "_retail` ensures that the new name doesn't overwrite the old name because I wanted it on the same sheet.

`RefersTo:=RetailSheet & intCount` sets the address of the new cell (`RetailSheet` is just a string `=Retail!$A$` and `intCount` ensures that the row is relative to the row on the retail sheet rather than the master sheet.

`On Error Resume Next` just moves to the next row if the cell is not named (which most aren't).